# What could cause a video to play poorly in VLC?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, qemu

I am playing a high quality (1080p) video using VLC inside a qemu-kvm virtual machine. The OS on my virtual machine is gentoo and the host OS is Ubuntu.

The video experience is very jerky : the video stops a lot, the verbose mode log has a lot of "PTS is out of range, dropping buffer" and "last picture skipped" messages.

The CPU utilization of the qemu process is nowhere close to 100%. Nor is the disk utilization. ( using Visual inspection of `top` and `iotop`).

What else could cause this problem ? What options could I try in vlc to figure out the problem ?

Comment: Don't look at the CPU utilization on the host, run top and iotop in your Gentoo guest and let us know what that says.

Comment: @DustinG looks like the CPU usage in guest is more than 90% most of the time video is playing. Why should the guest CPU utilization be so much more than the host ?

Comment: Because when you are virtualizing, the guest is getting a portion of what the Host has as far as hardware goes. So if you have a quad-core processor and you give the guest 1 core - then the guest is going to show a higher CPU utilization than the host because of relative resources available. Think of it this way, if 100% utilization on a single core is 25% utilization when looking at a quad core.

Comment: but when I do top, doesnt it show only the CPU utilization of the CPU on which the process is running ? I am running these tests on a machine with 12 cores

Comment: How many cores did you assign to the virtual?

Comment: %CPU in top shows you a percentage of all cores in the system. So on a 12 core system, one core at 100% would be 8.3%

Comment: I have assigned only 1 core to the virtual machine. Can it be that top shows a percent of cpu usage for only those CPUs assigned to the process ?

Comment: Seems like the irix mode on or off changes the behavior of top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would allocate more resources to the Virtual machine. Specifically, allocating more Cores and seeing if you can up the Video RAM. Virtual machines are not given access to 100% of the resources in your computer, just up to the maximum amount the Hypervisor (qemu-kvm in your case) allows. Keep in mind that your system is also using a virtualized graphics card as well so it is not as powerful as the graphics card as your host has access to - even if a Hypervisor allows advanced video features, there is till a performance penalty for the virtual devices emulation.

Comment: I think I need to investigate into more depth as to why the virtualized CPU usage is so high. Thanks for the tip

Comment: High-quality video will tax a single-cpu configuration, especially when it's not taking advantage of full video acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't qemu-kvm use vnc for its display? I guess that the video is decoded in software, and then the bitmaps are sent to vnc-viewer process, and then to X server, and then to the video card.

Also, CPU utilization. I think that linux doesn't separate %idle (waiting for the user) and
%wio (waiting for io). If a process waits for the grapics card, that is recorded as idle.

If you really want to view video from a virtual machine you probably need to look for something that can write directly to your graphics card. That is the vlc running in your vm
needs to use something like DRI to map your graphics card into vlc's own virtual memory space.

Comment: I think qemu-kvm  uses SDL by default, and vnc is optional. even if the video is decoded in software and it is not fast enough then  shouldn't I  see 100% CPU utilization? \