# VLC MMS video via network - stutters

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC to play a MMS video (1.5X speed) that is streamed from a "members only" website.

The video works great except that it hangs/stutters every **few** seconds.
So I increased the following settings, under `Tools -> Preferences -> Input/Codecs`, to their specified values:

1. File caching (ms) = 30000
2. Live Capture Caching (ms) = 30000
3. Disk caching (ms) = 30000
4. Network caching (ms) = 30000

But now it hangs every ~90 seconds, for a **longer** period of time (obviously, it tries to cache for 30 seconds.)

Is it possible to force VLC to automatically cache the video? Before the buffer is emptied.
Any advice as to how would I have a smooth video streaming?

VLC version: 2.0.8.
Ubuntu version: 12.04.5.

Comment: If the site doing the streaming is limiting your download bandwidth to the approximate network stream bandwidth then there is nothing you can do except watch the video at normal speed to avoid the buffering.

Comment: @Mokubai: I don't think that this is the case, because that in Windows this problem does not occur. But how do I figure if the bandwidth is limited by the site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What could cause a video to play poorly in VLC?](https://superuser.com/questions/421425/what-could-cause-a-video-to-play-poorly-in-vlc)